# Snowflake Go Sessions Keep Terminating

Tags: go, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the gosnowflake 1.40 driver. I am seeing my sessions cycle after 2 queries as seen in the image below, less than 1 second apart.

Connection setup looks something like this:

```
dsn, err := sf.DSN(sfConfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic("cannot get snowflake session: " + err.Error())
    }
    DBSession, err = sql.Open("snowflake", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic("cannot get snowflake session: " + err.Error())
    }
    return DBSession, nil
```

I use the following query pattern inside a function:

```
result = dbSession.QueryRow(command)
```

This session cycling pattern is not ideal, as I'd like to be able to assume a role and run multiple commands. Can someone point me to what I can do to make the Snowflake sessions persist? I don't have this problem using the WebUI.

[image: session cycling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB` maintains a pool of connections. Each connection in the pool will have a unique session ID. From [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB):

> DB is a database handle representing a pool of zero or more underlying connections. It's safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.
>
> The sql package creates and frees connections automatically; it also maintains a free pool of idle connections.

You have a couple options for bypassing the default behavior of cycling through the pool of connections:

1. Obtain a specific [`Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Conn) instance
   from the connection pool using
   [`DB.Conn()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Conn). The documentation
   specifically states:

   > Queries run on the same Conn will be run in the same database session.
2. Modify the connection pool parameters using
   [`DB.SetMaxOpenConns()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetMaxOpenConns).

   I suspect that setting this to `1` will also obtain the desired behavior.
   However, this introduces scalability/concurrency concerns that are
   addressed by having a connection pool in the first place.

Note, I'm not familiar with the Snowflake driver in particular. There may be other options that the driver supports.

Comment: Thank you, had completely missed the "session pool" part of the documentation. `Conn()` did the job. Curiously, setting the max connections to 1 only resulted in the job hanging.